# Cannot upload watch screenshots to App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-watch

I am facing an issue uploading new screenshot  in App Store Connect for my app

I had old screenshots (312x390, no alfa channel) that I deleted to upload the new ones.

Apple asks for screenshots for Series 3 or Series 6. I took new screenshots from both the Series 6 simulator and actual device (44mm device, 368x448, alfa channel) but when I upload them they hung forever, without any error message:

[image]

If I upload the old screenshots they load instantly without any problem.

What I have tried so far:

- Using different browser (firefox, chrome, safari)
- Removing the alfa channel
- Resizing to 312x390 (with or without alpha channel)
- Wait for a while

Everything fails.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: App Store Connect is having issues right now. It doesn't seem to be loading properly for a lot of people and those that do get it to load are unable to use it properly. While the [Developer System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) seems fine, there's a banner in Trends that states that "Data in sales reports and dashboards is delayed. We are working to resolve the issue as soon as possible and apologize for any inconvenience." So just try again in a few hours.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. It was driving me nuts.

Comment: Check this solution, this will likely help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313352/app-store-screenshots-screenshot-uploads-in-progress-error-appscreenshotse