# App Store Screenshots - "Screenshot uploads in progress" Error / appScreenshotSets Error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is going to be self-answered question. This issue is wasting days and whole weeks of developer time.

See the screenshots below to see what the problem is. Apple developer forum doesn't provide you any answers.

The issue is:

Apple App Store shows no screenshots because of App Store's web interface issue. When you try to upload new screenshots it does not let you do that. It throws a STATE_ERROR with a message of 'Screenshots already exists!'.

[image: App Store Shows No Screenshots even when previously uploaded screenshots exist]

[image: Console shows UNEXPECTED_ERROR from App Store API]

[image: AppScreenshotSets throwing a 500 Error]

Answer (score 11):

The way you resolve this is to use the App Store Connect API to delete the AppScreenshotSets for all your "Preparing for submission" review version.

Steps to follow:

1. Generate an API keys. Go to **"App Store Connect" > "Users & Access" > "Keys"** (tab).
2. Use the ISSUER_ID, KEY_ID, AUTH KEY FILE (.p8 file) to create **time-sensitive token** using the ruby script below:

   ```
   require "base64"
   require "jwt"
   ISSUER_ID = "XXXX-XX-XXXXXX-XX-XXXXXXXX"
   KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXX"
   private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read("AuthKey_XXXXXX.p8"))
   token = JWT.encode(
      {
       iss: "XXXX-XX-XXXXXX-XX-XXXXXXXX",
       exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
       aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
      },
      private_key,
      "ES256",
      header_fields={
        kid: "XXXXXXXXX" }
    )
   puts token
   ```
3. Run the script with ruby

   ```
   ruby generateTokenFromCredentials.rb
   ```
4. Export the time sensitive token in terminal:

   ```
   export APPSTORETOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   ```
5. [**OPTIONAL STEP**] Get additional information about your app store app

   ```
   export APPSTORETOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

   //List user
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"

   //List Apps
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"


   //Get App Store Versions
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/<APP_STORE_ID_NUMBER>/relationships/appStoreVersions'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"


   //List All App Store Version Localizations for an App Store Version
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/appStoreVersions/<APP_STORE_ID_NUMBER>/appStoreVersionLocalizations'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"


   //Review submissions
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/<APP_STORE_ID_NUMBER>/reviewSubmissions'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"



   //Pre release versions 
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/<APP_STORE_ID_NUMBER>/preReleaseVersions'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"


   //Get App Info
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/<APP_STORE_ID_NUMBER>/appInfos'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"
   ```
6. Find out the **appStoreVersionLocalizations** from the Google Chrome or Safari Console by going to the request that threw the 500 Error.

   ```
   curl 'https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/iris/v1/appScreenshotSets?include=appScreenshots&filter\[appStoreVersionLocalization\]=XXXXX-XX-XX-XX-XXXXXXX' \
     -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"' \
     -H 'x-csrf-itc: [asc-ui]' \
   ```

   Take appStoreVersionLocalization from the URL
7. List all the **appScreenshotSets** and get the ids:

   ```
   //List all relavant App Screenshots
   curl 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/appStoreVersionLocalizations/21XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/appScreenshotSets'  --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"
   ```
8. **DELETE EVERY LAST ONE OF THEM**

   ```
   //Delete Screenshots Sets
   curl -X DELETE 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/appScreenshotSets/<XXXXX-XXX-XXX-XX-XXXX>' --Header "Authorization: Bearer $APPSTORETOKEN"
   ```

Now you can go back to the App Store Connect web interface and continue your uploads.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is:

1. Just Change Version name or edit some text.
2. You can see Submit button is enabled before click submit button upload screenshots and click "submit" button. Add to review button also working fine then you can release your app successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Of all the times this has been asked and answered over the years this is the one that worked for us.  We removed the description which gave us the missing description error.  Then added the description back in.  Success.

Answer (score 0):

I exported some screenshots to `png` fileformat using `8bpc RGB` pixel format with GIMP. Those screenshots were accepted by the AppStore as of end of 2023.  What pixel format the images used before the story however doesn't tell as it was set to 'automatic pixel format'.

Answer (score 0):

Me too I was having problem uploading with Safari for hours then I tried in brave browser and finally could upload.